How to work multiple users in the same geopackage using QGIS
I'm having a problem when multiple users have to access, manipulate or just view the same database.
Sometimes the user needs to edit some information in the rows of the attribute table, or to change the vertices of the polygon, or just look for visual information. But if this is done simultaneously, there may be an error, including losing all data.
I was trying to export the attribute table rows to Excel and make the necessary edits and then put them back into the shapefile attribute table. But it did not work!
Has anyone had the same problem and solved it, or if they didn't, but know the solution?

SQLite is not designed for that kind of usage https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html. Use PostGIS instead.

never use excel to edit attribute tables, QGis can edit them in place with no risk of data loss
